# Cuando creas una base de datos en MySQL Shell ¿Donde se guarda esa base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy empezando en MySQL y empece a crear bases de datos en su Shell, lo que me di cuenta es que no puedo moverme entre directorios. Ya cree unas bases de datos, pero quisiera saber donde se guardan, y si esas ¿deben de permanecer ahí?, o ¿deben de crearse en la carpeta de tu proyecto?

Comment: ¿Te refieres al shell de mysql? Pues se guardan en el motor al que te conectas, probablemente al motor instalado en tu equipo.

Comment: Revisa `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE '%dir'`

Comment: Si tu pregunta es si al crearlas en el shell se crean en un lugar distinto que al crearlas desde otra herramienta, la respuesta es no. Siempre se crean en el mismo sitio. Si no, no veo que relevancia tiene mencionar al shell dentro de la pregunta.